# Why do I get this error? addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

Why is it that the following code does not work?
The console prints are tests I did to make sure I was accessing the elements correctly. When I do `typeof addEventListener` it returns function. But then when I try to actually add an event it returns the error: "Uncaught TypeError: thumbnails[key].addEventListener is not a function" and I can't figure out why.
Can anybody help?

```
var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName("small");
var previewImage = document.getElementById("large");
var caption = document.getElementById("captionText");

for(var key in thumbnails) {
    console.log(key + " -> " + thumbnails[key].src);
    console.log(typeof thumbnails[key].addEventListener);
    thumbnails[key].addEventListener("click", function(){
        previewImage.src = thumbnails[key].src;
        caption.innerHTML = thumbnails[key].alt;
    });
}
```

Comment: `When I do typeof addEventListener it returns function` - for every key? What type of object is `thumbnails`?

Comment: And what you get when if you console log, thumbnails[key]?

Comment: You're probably picking up an extraneous property on `thumbnails`. If it's an array, do a regular `for (var i=0;` type loop on it instead of using `for...in`. It it's an object, add a `hasOwnProperty` check.

Comment: @JaromandaX I forgot to include the line where I create thumbnails. I get it from `getEmentsByClassName();` so it's a node list object. I did a `hasOwnProperty` check on `thumbnails[key]` like @torazaburo and @MiguelLattuada suggested and it returned false